# Sum of numbers from a file in PHP

Tags: php, file

Given a file with numbers, I need to calculate and display their sum using PHP. This is what I have done so far, but the result displayed is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$file = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
$sum = 0;

while(!feof($file)){
    $num = (int) fgetc($file);
    $sum = $sum + $num;
}

echo $sum;
fclose($file);

?>
```

The file looks like this:

```
1 3 10 7 9
```

Comment: what is the exact problem? Is the sum not correct?
can you also show what file.txt looks like please?

Comment: The file has these numbers: 1 3 10 7 9. So the sum should be 30, but the result displayed is 21, which is not correct

Comment: Please add `file.txt` to your question. We don't know if `1 3 10 7 9` using space or new line

Comment: I just added the file. It contains spaces between numbers.

Comment: Note: `1 + 3 + 1 + 0 + 7 + 9 == 21` (A possible reason why you get 21)

Comment: was about to post the same @DefinitelynotRafal. The calculation is correct, the logic is incorrect.

Comment: Ohh I get it now. But is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @UserL00 you have 3 options/answers. Choose one that works best for you and accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of values and return the [sum of the array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).

```
$file = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
$values = [];

while(!feof($file)){
    $values = array_merge(explode(' ', $file), $values);
}

echo array_sum($values);
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer :

```
$file = trim(file('file.txt')[0]);
$sum = array_sum(explode(' ', $file));

var_dump($sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it will work fine

```
$file = fopen('num.txt', 'r');
  $sum = 0;
  $lc =0;   //last char
  $cc = ''; //current char
  while(!feof($file)){
      $cc = (int) fgetc($file);
      if($cc == ' '){
        $sum = $lc + $sum;
        $lc = ' ';
      }else if($cc != ' '){
          $lc = $lc+$cc;
      }
  }
  echo $sum;
  fclose($file);
```